# Symfony2 not reading form parameter.yml file on production

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, centos6, symfony-2.8

good monday! I have a working Symfony2 Proyect, developed in my computer (MacOs) and also formerly deployed in heroku, but when I deployed in CentOS with apache Vhost.
My website works but the database connection is not working.
my parameters.yml file:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: dbname
    database_user: dbuser
    database_password: 8xFfdsaFDSCK
```

My config.yml file:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        server_version: 5.6
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

My config_prod.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

#framework:
#    validation:
#        cache: validator.mapping.cache.apc
#    serializer:
#        cache: serializer.mapping.cache.apc

#doctrine:
#    orm:
#        metadata_cache_driver: apc
#        result_cache_driver: apc
#        query_cache_driver: apc

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
```

and I'm still getting an error on database connection:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                                                      
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What am I missing to tell the user, password and database??

Comment: Probably an order issue.  What motivated you to move the import parameters.yml from config.yml to config_prod.yml?  Try putting it back and see what happens.  By the way, if that is your real database password in your question then you might consider changing it.

Comment: it is not my real password (I'm noob but not that noob) I tried without moving parameters.yml to config_prod.yml and didn't work, I guess I was just kinda desperate :D

Comment: And are you rebuilding the production cache each time you make a change?

Comment: yep, I'm using php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug, but for some reason all those combined with other things (like reset apache, and change 127.0.0.1 for localhost) did the trick, thanks!